# JPA QueryException: The list of fields to insert into the table is empty

Tags: jpa

I actually have a problem with JPA. He is complaining about one 
of my Entities:

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-6023] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The list of fields to insert into the table [DatabaseTable(TBL_SPJ_CAST_MOVIE)] is empty.  You must define at least one mapping for this table.
```

After some researching i found out that this Exception appears when 
there are no columns defined in the Entity classe because ofcourse
you cant insert Data into an empty Table.

However i have actually two columns defined in my Entity. One for the id
and one for a foreign key to a m:n table:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_SPJ_CAST_MOVIE")
public class CastMovie implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="CAST_MOVIE_ID", unique=true)
    private int castID = 0;
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="TBL_SPJ_CAST_ROLE", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="CAST_MOVIE_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID")})
    private List<Role> roles = null;

    public CastMovie() {}

    public int getCastID() {
        return castID;
    }
    public void setCastID(int castID) {
        this.castID = castID;
    }
    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

So whats the point of this Error? All Data coming from a xml file so i cant
put in more columns (if thats the problem).

EDIT:

Here is the structure of the four tables involved in this problem:

[image]

- One Movie has one Cast -> Relationship One to One
- Many Casts have many Rols -> Relationship Many to Many

Comment: can you post your table structure?

Comment: did. there are ofcourse much more tables but this four tables are the only tables effecting the TBL_SPJ_CAST_MOVIE

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Set the `GenerationType` of id field to `GenerationType.TABLE` and it will do the trick.
Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272819/insert-row-to-table-with-the-only-identifier-column-with-eclipselink)